# edit google earth polygon

Tags: javascript, google-earth-plugin

i need some good advice on how to achieve polygon editing in google earth plugin.
My application is capable of creating polygon from mouse click but i cannot understand how to let the user edit previous saved polygon instances. I mean, i'd like to click on a polygon's vertex to select it and then click on some other point in the map to move it there (like [drag and drop example](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?exp=earth#draggable_placemark) available on code playground).
However, reading the API documentation it seems to me that a vertex has not support for event handling (click, mouseover, etc.).
Any help is greatly appreciated.

PS: i made a [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/andreapier/8gHtQ/1/) to let you help with some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i was able to solve the issue by myself.
I made a complete working [jsfiddle example here](http://jsfiddle.net/andreapier/8gHtQ/2/). It has just some left issues with final vertex location but i suspect it has something to do with altitude. I highly doubt it is my code. However, if you find the issue report back plase.
Hope that will help someone!
Bye